# Looking for a pdf reader that show meaning a word in whole document when you highlight

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am looking for a PDF Reader for IOS that when you translate a word in the document then I want to see meaning of word in whole document with same word so when I click same word I want to see the meaning of the word straight away. 
Sorry about my English guys. Also might a complicated feature that I want

Edit: I think same feature in Moon+Reader app but this is a Google Play store app.

Comment: Adobe already has that, it is called 'Look up selected word' does that not work for you

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. It looks the best option so far. The only thing is you can see all highlights in same place and after many pages if you have so many highlights and you can spend time for finding words again. Also my idea was when you highlight a word than automatically highlight all same word in the document.

Comment: Adobe Reader can not do that but the paid version of Acrobat can. http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2010/04/searching-and-marking-multiple-words-in-a-pdf/